# SharePoint org browser not showing images

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, organization-browser

I am using SharePoint org browser in one of publishing site. Problem is sometimes it loads data and sometimes doesn't. Similarly if it loads data then sometimes it shows images and sometimes doesn't.
I can't seem to reproduce this bug. It shows different results on different machines. Looks like there is some permission issue?
Both MySite and my publishing site are on different web applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think(from tag) you are using sharepoint 2013 and cliam based web applications, did you implement this fix. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2643420/de
Check these 2 link, they discuss the same issue.

[Link 1](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/e5b46601-c500-46ff-b3f0-e8ed8e6552c2/sharepoint2013-organizational-browser-not-showing-anything?forum=sharepointgeneral)
[Link 2](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/06eff633-091d-487e-a157-071b138a5114/organization-browser-webpart-shows-no-pictures?forum=sharepointadminprevious)